# Can I include the verb 'to be' in the sequence of homogeneous parts of a sentence?

Tags: grammar

> The problem remains pressing and is difficult to resolve.

I have a doubtful feeling about 'and is' but don't see any grammatical issues with it. Or, say,

> Jim goes to the gym, follows a healthy diet, and is in good shape.

Is it okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you intended with the latter sentence.

you can include `to be` without grammatical error.
But if I were you ,

I would rather write *Jim goes to the gym, following a healthy diet, so that he could be in a good shape.*

Comment: Your preference in this case is idiosyncratic.

Comment: I would definitely prefer the version in the OP over your sentence, which is much harder to understand.